# Understanding Array Project

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

I have a project that is asking the following: 
In this exercise you will complete a class that implements a shopping cart as an array of items. The file Item.java contains the definition of a class named Item that models an item one would purchase. An item has a name, price, and quantity (the quantity purchased). The file ShoppingCart.java implements the shopping cart as an array of Item objects.

I have a total of three codes that were given to us and I've completed them:
I believe these are the classes:

```
// ***************************************************************
//   Item.java
//   Represents an item in a shopping cart.
// ***************************************************************

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item
{
   private String name;
   private double price;
   private int quantity;


   // -------------------------------------------------------

   //  Create a new item with the given attributes.

   // -------------------------------------------------------

   public Item (String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased)
   {
      name = itemName;
      price = itemPrice;
      quantity = numPurchased;
   }

   // -------------------------------------------------------
   //   Return a string with the information about the item
   // -------------------------------------------------------

   public String toString()
   {
      NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

  return (name + "\t" + fmt.format(price) + "\t" + quantity + "\t"+ fmt.format(price*quantity));
   } 

   // -------------------------------------------------
   //   Returns the unit price of the item
   // -------------------------------------------------
   public double getPrice()
   {
      return price;
   }


   // -------------------------------------------------
   //   Returns the name of the item
   // -------------------------------------------------
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the quantity of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public int getQuantity()
    {
      return quantity;
    }

    // **********************************************************************
    //   ShoppingCart.java
    //   Represents a shopping cart as an array of items
    // **********************************************************************


   public class ShoppingCart
{
   private int itemCount;  //total number of items in the cart
   private double totalPrice;  //total prive of items in the cart
   private Item[] cart;
   private int capacity;

   // -----------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty shopping cart with a capacity of 5 items.
   // -----------------------------------------------------------
   public ShoppingCart()
   {
      cart = new Item[capacity];
      capacity = 5;
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;

   {

   // -------------------------------------------------------
   //  Adds an item to the shopping cart.  

   // Check to make sure there is room in the cart first

   // -------------------------------------------------------

   public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
   {
      Item temp = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
      totalPrice += (price * quantity);
      itemCount += 1;
      cart[itemCount] = temp;
     if (itemCount==capacity)
  {
     increaseSize();
  }
   }

   // -------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the contents of the cart together with
   //  summary information.
   // -------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
  NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

      String contents = "\nShopping Cart\n";
      contents += "\nItem\t\Unit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";

       for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
      contents += cart[i] + "\n";
      contents += "\nTotal Price: " + fmt.format(totalPrice);
      contents += "\n";

      return contents;
    }

     // ---------------------------------------------------------
     //  Increases the capacity of the shopping cart by 3
     // ---------------------------------------------------------
     private void increaseSize()
     {
     Item[] temp = new Item[capacity+3];
     for(int i=0; i < capacity; i++)
     {
        tempt[i] = cart[i];
     }
     cart = temp;
     temp = null;
     capacity = cart.length;
  }

}
```

And this is the main:

```
//***************************************************************
//   Shop.java
//   Uses the Item class to create items and add them to a shopping
//   cart stored in a ShoppingCart class
// ***************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;


import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Shop
{    

public static void main (String[] args)

{

  ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();


  Item item;

  String itemName;

  double itemPrice;

  int quantity;



  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  String keepShopping = "y";
  ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();

  do

    {

     System.out.print("Enter the name of the item: ");
     itemName = scan.next();

     System.out.print("Enter the unit price: ");
     itemPrice = scan.nextDouble();

     System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
     quantity = scan.nextInt();
         // *** add this item to the cart by passing itemName, itemPrce, and quantity to the addToCart method.
     cart.addToCart(itemName, itemPrice, quantity);

         // *** print the contents of the cart object using the toString method of the ShoppingCart class.

     System.out.println(cart);

     System.out.print("Continue shopping (y/n)?");
     keepShopping = scan.next();


  }

      while (keepShopping.equals("y"));
      // *** print the final total of the grocery list with a “Please pay ...” in front of the toalPrice. 
   }
}
```

My question is did I arrange the codes correctly? Because The class does not compile I get illegal starts errors and I'm having trouble with the main.
Any help is appreciated.

The class error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Item.java
Item.java:95: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
      ^
Item.java:95: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
      ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                    ^
Item.java:95: error: <identifier> expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                     ^
Item.java:95: error: not a statement
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                             ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                  ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                                ^
Item.java:111: error: illegal start of expression
public String toString()
^
Item.java:111: error: ';' expected
public String toString()
                     ^
Item.java:116: error: illegal escape character
  contents += "\nItem\t\Unit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";
                        ^
Item.java:130: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
 ^
Item.java:130: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
         ^
Item.java:130: error: ';' expected
 private void increaseSize()
                          ^
Item.java:147: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
14 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

The main method error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Shop.java
Item.java:95: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
^
Item.java:95: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
      ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                    ^
Item.java:95: error: <identifier> expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                     ^
Item.java:95: error: not a statement
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                             ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                  ^
Item.java:95: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                                ^
Item.java:111: error: illegal start of expression
public String toString()
^
Item.java:111: error: ';' expected
public String toString()
                     ^
Item.java:116: error: illegal escape character
  contents += "\nItem\t\Unit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";
                        ^
Item.java:130: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
 ^
Item.java:130: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
         ^
Item.java:130: error: ';' expected
 private void increaseSize()
                          ^
Item.java:147: error: reached end of file while parsing
 }
  ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
      ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                    ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: <identifier> expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                     ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: not a statement
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                             ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                  ^
ShoppingCart.java:34: error: ';' expected
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
                                                                ^
ShoppingCart.java:50: error: illegal start of expression
public String toString()
^
ShoppingCart.java:50: error: ';' expected
public String toString()
                     ^
ShoppingCart.java:55: error: illegal escape character
  contents += "\nItem\t\Unit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";
                        ^
ShoppingCart.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
 ^
ShoppingCart.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
 private void increaseSize()
         ^
ShoppingCart.java:69: error: ';' expected
 private void increaseSize()
                          ^
ShoppingCart.java:82: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
^
Shop.java:33: error: variable cart is already defined in method main(String[])
  ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
               ^
Shop.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
     cart.addToCart(itemName, itemPrice, quantity);
         ^
   symbol:   method addToCart(String,double,int)
   location: variable cart of type ArrayList<Item> 
   Item.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
     increaseSize();
     ^
   symbol:   method increaseSize()
   location: class Item.ShoppingCart
   Item.java:124: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
   return contents;
         ^
   Item.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
        tempt[i] = cart[i];
        ^
   symbol:   variable tempt
   location: class Item.ShoppingCart
   ShoppingCart.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
      Item temp = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
                                 ^
   symbol:   variable price
   location: class ShoppingCart
   ShoppingCart.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
  totalPrice += (price * quantity);
                 ^
   symbol:   variable price
   location: class ShoppingCart
    ShoppingCart.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
     increaseSize();
     ^
   symbol:   method increaseSize()
   location: class ShoppingCart
   ShoppingCart.java:63: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
   return contents;
         ^
    ShoppingCart.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
        tempt[i] = cart[i];
        ^
   symbol:   variable tempt
   location: class ShoppingCart
   38 errors

----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Post the exact error messages here.

Comment: ^^That and what exact line it's pointing to

Comment: Also, take note that you have 2 variables with the same name. You have `ArrayList<Item> cart` and `ShoppingCart cart` which will cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestion on my opinion :

The ShoppingCart should hold only the Item array object.Iterate the Item array object to get the total price , quantity and capacity.The constructor can be kept only to accept the item array.

After you add the Items to the cart , you can call methods defined in the cart as example totalPrice,totalQuantity to get the required details of your project.

You can refer to the following link :
http://www.journaldev.com/1754/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, one of the biggest issues that I see is that you use 'cart' twice: once as an ArrayList, and once as a ShoppingCart. Doing this will confuse the application, as it doesn't know where to pull from.

When you say 'cart.addToCart(itemName, itemPrice, quantity);', the application won't immediately know whether you're trying to add the information to the ArrayList, or to the ShoppingCart.

Also, I see a couple of issues with your methods.

In your "toString()" method, I would rename it. "toString()" is a code that allows you to convert certain variables to a string, and it is a code that is already defined in Java. That's why it's telling you that a ';' is expected; because, typically it would be "thisVariable.toString();". Does that make sense?

Also, still in your "toString()" class, I see that you have typed:

"contents += "\nItem\t\Unit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";".

This should be changed to:

"contents += "\nItem\tUnit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";".

You had an extra backslash in the line. I think that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public ShoppingCart()
   {
      cart = new Item[capacity];
      capacity = 5;
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
```

You are missing closing bracket '}' on constructor for ShoppingCart. It should be the following.

```
   public ShoppingCart()
   {
      cart = new Item[capacity];
      capacity = 5;
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
   }
```